# Overwriting quality gate in sonar

Tags: sonarqube

Is there a way to overwrite the quality gate status of a Sonarqube (5.6) project?

Use case is that we check for technical dept on new code to not be higher than 5%. In case there are additional rules activated in the quality profile, next time a project was checked it will violate the quality gate, even though the technical dept was not introduced by new code but with new rules instead.

Comment: This question duplicates the following thread in the SonarQube Google Group : https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/sonarqube/vphmJoonATc/w7Fpx7W1CQAJ

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to overwrite quality gate status. From [this thread on Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/sonarqube/vphmJoonATc/w7Fpx7W1CQAJ) by G. Ann Campbell:

> There's not. The best approach is a strategy one: only update the profile / add rules when a new version is just beginning.
>
> Of course, that doesn't really address the issue that new rules raise "new" issues on old code. For that I don't have an answer.